# She was told a joke

Tags: complements, objects

> She was told a joke

Is *a joke* an object here? Or maybe a compulsory adjunct? Cuz I think *she was told* doesn't make sense on its own.

I'm confused, can someone help?

Comment: *She was told* makes sense.  It's just the passive voice: someone told her, but it doesn't matter who, or we don't know who.

Comment: You don't have to post thank-you comments to answers. If you find an answer helpful, please upvote and/or accept it. You have asked 43 questions on our site but have accepted no answers, which I find kind of puzzling.

Answer (score 1):

Compare the ditransitive verb **give**:

- He gave her a book. - Active voice; subject is the agent, direct object is the thing given, indirect object is the recipient
- He gave a book to her. - Active voice; subject is the agent, direct object is the thing given, prepositional *to*-phrase contains the recipient
- She was given a book. - Passive voice; subject is the recipient, direct object is the thing given
- A book was given to her. - Passive voice; subject is the thing given, prepositional *to*-phrase contains the recipient

Answer (score 0):

Yes, *a joke* is an object. **To tell** is a transitive verb and requires a direct object.

Comment: But you do also find **tell** used intransitively, as in: **I knew who was responsible but I had promised not to tell.**  https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/tell